# Segmentation fault when reading in to an array

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct, segmentation-fault

I have this function for printing results. Now, I am trying to store names in to the array of structs, but for some reason I am getting a segmentation fault. According to debbuger the segmentation error occurs at the first entry when `pos` is still 0;

When I try to print the `name` from `races` it displays as expected.

```
race_node print_championship(race_node *races, int num_races, member_node tree_top) {

    championship_node championship_array[num_races*PLACES];
    int pos=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_races; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < PLACES; j++) {
            strcpy(championship_array[pos]->name, races[i]->rd_arr[j].name);
            pos++;
        }
    }
}
```

structs definitions:

```
typedef struct race_details * race_details_node;
typedef struct race * race_node;
typedef struct championship * championship_node;

typedef struct race{
    char date[DATE];
    char race_date[RACE_DATE];
    int boats_num;
    struct race_details * rd_arr;

}race;

typedef struct race_details{
    int mem_id;
    int points;
    char boat_class[BOAT_CLASS];
    char name[NAME];
    int time;

}race_details;

typedef struct championship{
    int total_points;
    char boat_name[BOAT_NAME];
    char name[NAME];

}championship;
```

It does not seem to go out of the array bounds and memory usage seem also fine, am I missing something?

Comment: Well, you have to show _a lot_ more then a single function. Each one of the pointers you dereference can be invalid, and the variable length array may not be enough fot the stack. Show enough code for others to reproduce the  error you are getting. `It does not seem to go out of the array bounds and memory usage seem also fine, am I missing something?` - your memory usage is definitely wrong, in `championship_array[pos]->` you are derefencing uninitialized pointer. Because exactly such cases are hard to spot, pointer typedefs are discouraged.Where do you think `championship_array[pos]` points?

Comment: Your `championship_node` array is actually an array of pointers to `championship`. None of them is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

```
championship_node championship_array[num_races*PLACES];
```

Since `championship_node` is an alias for a **pointer** type you're declaring an array of pointers here. None of them is initialised; none of them points to a valid object.

Thus when you use / dereference one of these you get undefined behavior; in your case a segmentation fault.

Normally I make suggestions on how to fix the issue ... but I'm not sure here what you wanted to achieve (the print function isn't printing after all?).  You could either use `championship` instead to have an variable size array of such objects on the stack or allocate memory using `malloc` to initialise the pointers.